# If the beginning of the array begins with null values, `spanGaps:true` is not working

Tags: chart.js, react-chartjs

#### Problem

If use `spanGaps:true` in line chart, lines will be drawn between points with no or null data.
This option works perfectly in most of the case, but when `datasets.data` array begins with `null` values line is not drawn.

#### TO-BE

If data array begins with `null` value, I want the graph to be drawn.
For example, if `data[0] = null`, I want the graph to look the same as when `data[0] = 0`.

Problem Example : https://codepen.io/younyikim/pen/zYMbGMM